# Path displayed when running a Java file in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have included the .jar files coming with JavaFX in my project and can successfully run JavaFX-based classes. What I find rather odd is that when a file that doesn't feature GUI runs, IntelliJ keeps displaying the following message relating to JavaFX library path. How can I get rid of it?

```java
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=53055:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\new\out\production\new;C:\Users\User\Desktop\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\src.zip;C:\Users\User\Desktop\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Users\User\Desktop\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Users\User\Desktop\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Users\User\Desktop\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Users\User\Desktop\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Users\User\Desktop\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Users\User\Desktop\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Users\User\Desktop\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib\javafx.graphics.jar ArrayListTest
```

Comment: If both your main classes are part of the same module then that makes perfect sense. [A library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#) is applied per module, not per class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the libraries and SDKs thare you see in the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies) will be added to the classpath when running.

In case the second app is unrelated to the first one, it makes sense to move it into a separate module or even a separate project where you can use different libraries/classpath.

In the run/debug configuration you can specify classpath of which module should be used for running.